# Writing a text file into an array and reading a particular line VB

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to output a specific line from a text file into an array, where each `Button` will produce a different line. For example `Button1` should output the first line in the text file and `Button2` should output the second line in the text file.

Text file:

> Red
>   Blue
>   Orange
>   Green

When I press `Button1` I get the first line in the `TextBox` ("Red") however when I press `Button2` I still get "Red".

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqYPQ.png)

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim character As String = ""

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        i = 0
        readfile()
        TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text + character
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        i = 1
        readfile()
        TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text + character
    End Sub

    Sub readfile()
        Dim SR As New StreamReader("Colours.txt")
        Dim Characters(3) As String
        Do Until SR.Peek = -1
            character = SR.ReadLine
            Characters(i) = character
        Loop
        SR.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Can you fix the format of your code? And what's `Characters()` for...it doesn't seem to be used for anything? Is your text file a single line of text with 4 words or 4 lines with 1 word on each?

Comment: sorry about that, yes my text file is 4 lines with 1 word on each line

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using `File.ReadAllLines` to read the lines text file into a `String` array in the form's `Load` event. Then your `Button.Click` events can just copy the required line into the `TextBox`.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private lines() As String

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        lines = IO.File.ReadAllLines("Colours.txt")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        TextBox1.Text = lines(0)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        TextBox1.Text = lines(1)
    End Sub
End Class
```

In your question, it's not clear if you want to just store the selected line in the `TextBox`, or append the line to the `TextBox`. If you want to append, you can use `TextBox1.Text &= lines(0) 'or lines(1)` (using `&=` instead of `=`) although in that case, you probably also want to add some kind of separator.