# Randomizing lines in a text file

Tags: vb.net

I have a text file which is made a for a multiple choice question and answer form. I want to call 4 lines at a time and output these 4 values in a label. For presentation purposes each line would have one word so the user would have to choose between option 1 - 4 for example

1. Red
2. Blue
3. Green
4. Yellow

However I want to randomize a selection of four values for 3 labels but my file would have enough values for 6 labels, this way each time the user loads the program it doesn't repeat the questions.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdBYD.png) is what my text file looks like

```
Public Class Form1
Dim rand As New Random
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim QuestionFile As New IO.StreamReader(CurDir() & "\" & "Questions.txt")
    Dim fileContentsQ As String = QuestionFile.ReadToEnd
    Dim fileListQ As New List(Of String)
    For Each Str As String In fileContentsQ.Split(CChar(vbCrLf))
        fileListQ.Add(Str)
    Next
    Dim randItem As Integer = rand.Next(0, fileListQ.Count - 1)
    Label1.Text = (fileListQ.Item(randItem))
    fileListQ.RemoveAt(randItem)
    'removes item from list so that it isn't repeated
    Dim randItem2 As Integer = rand.Next(0, fileListQ.Count - 1)
    Label2.Text = (fileListQ.Item(randItem))
    fileListQ.RemoveAt(randItem)
    Dim randItem3 As Integer = rand.Next(0, fileListQ.Count - 1)
    Label3.Text = (fileListQ.Item(randItem))
    fileListQ.RemoveAt(randItem)
End Sub
```

End Class

The problem is that each label only shows one word/line when i would want it to show 4 words at a time, e.g `Label1` could be (all underneath each other):

> Red
>   Blue
>   Green
>   Yellow

Comment: you need to be clearer about what you want - a label isnt going to show bulletpoint for instance. But you are probably going to have to glue the set together to show them all at once

Comment: That parsed list will only be available in Form load.  If there a Next button to show a new question, you will have to read and parse the file again. You should use the code in the answer to your [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35686834/1070452) where Mr Blackwood made it global to the form for reuse

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim lst As New List(Of String)(IO.File.ReadAllLines("Archivo.txt"))
Dim nst As New List(Of String)
Randomize()
While lst.Count > 0
     Dim rdi As Integer = CInt(Math.Floor(Rnd() * lst.Count))
     nst.Add(lst(rdi))
     lst.RemoveAt(rdi)
End While
IO.File.WriteAllLines("Archivo.txt", nst.ToArray, Encoding.Unicode)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please care to explain the code in the context of question.